# How to check is a mpi code success or not in bash?

Tags: bash, mpi

I want to automatically check a lot of executable files run success or not in bash.

Suppose I have an exeutable file `a.out`.

I can check it success or not in bash by

```
./a.out
if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "code error!"
fi
```

If the exeutable file run by mpi

```
mpirun -np 4 ./a.out // run the code by 4 processes
```

I can not check the executable file is ok or not by the same way above. Because at this case the `$?` indicate that `mpirun` is success or not.

So how can I check a mpi code is success or not in bash?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A well written MPI program should
 - upon success: have all tasks call `MPI_Finalize()` and end up `exit(0)`
 - upon failure: call `MPI_Abort()` and end up `exit(rc)` with a non zero error code (note is is likely `MPI_Abort()` by a single MPI task will abort the entire job even if `exit()` is never invoked.

And then it is up to the MPI library to have `mpirun` exit with a zero error status on success, and a non zero error status on failure.

Bottom line, if `a.out` is well written, it does not matter if it is an MPI app or not.

Comment: Thanks for explaination, and a little beside question, I am using C and a lot of  `assert` in `<assert.h>` exists in the MPI code. It seems that if the assert failed, the MPI_Abort() will be not called.  Change all `assert(...)` to `if... MPI_Abort(...)` must can help. Do you have any suggestions to deal with the issue?

Comment: that sounds like the right approach. I would replace `assert(...)` with `assert_mpi(...)` and then create the `assert_mpi()` macro as you described it. `assert()` is a no-op if the `NDEBUG` macro is defined (e.g. it does nothing if a program is compiled in non debug mode), so you might want to mimic that (see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/assert_h)